# Can't access Django Webpage on Ubuntu 14.04 AWS Server?

Tags: python, django, ubuntu, apache2, mod-wsgi

After launching an Ubuntu 14.04 AWS instance updating and upgrading the server, getting pip3, and successfully installing Apache2. 
Changing the /etc/apache2/sites-enabled/000-default.conf file to look like:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
        <Directory /var/www/test>
                Options +ExecCGI
                DirectoryIndex index.py
        </Directory>
        AddHandler cgi-script .py

        ...

        DocumentRoot /var/www/test

        ...
```

Installing mod_wsgi using:

```
sudo apt-get install libapache2-mod-wsgi-py3
```

Changing the Apache2.conf file to look like:

```
   WSGIScriptAlias / /var/www/html/myproject/myproject/myproject/wsgi.py
     WSGIPythonPath /var/www/html/myproject/myproject
     <Directory /var/www/html/myproject/myproject/myproject>
     <Files wsgi.py>
     Require all granted
     </Files>
     </Directory>
```

and making migrations, and running the server by typing:

```
python3 manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:8000
```

I tried to view it at the publicdns:8000 but it said the site was unavailable. Any suggestions on getting this up and running would be greatly appreciated. 
Thanks.

EDIT: As requested here is the settings.py file:

```
 },
]


# Internationalization
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/topics/i18n/

LANGUAGE_CODE = 'en-us'

TIME_ZONE = 'UTC'

USE_I18N = True

USE_L10N = True

USE_TZ = True


# Static files (CSS, JavaScript, Images)
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/howto/static-files/

STATIC_URL = '/static/'
STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, "static/")
```

Here is a curl of the webserver:

```
 curl -i http://ipaddress
    HTTP/1.0 503 Service Unavailable
    Cache-Control: no-cache
    Connection: close
    Content-Type: text/html

    <html><body><h1>503 Service Unavailable</h1>
    No server is available to handle this request.
    </body></html>
```

Curl -i with port didn't return anything at all.

Comment: What precisely said `the site was unavailable`? Can you post the output you get with `curl -i  publicdns:8000`? What does the apache error log say?

Comment: Could you also post your settings files, ensure your allowed_hosts is configured properly

Comment: If you want to be using Apache/mod_wsgi, you wouldn't be running ``python3 manage.py run server`` to get it started. You need to be restarting Apache after the configuration changes. Apache is also listening on port 80, not 8000.